# Using Column Counting in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I made a website in HTML, CSS and this is what the page looks like:
[menu page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li0zH.png).
html code:

```
<div class="tabcontent menu ">
                <div class="menu-item">       
                   .
                   . 
                   .                
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">       
                   .
                   . 
                   .                
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">       
                   .
                   . 
                   .                
                </div>

           
            </div>
```

css code :

```
.tabcontent {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-column-gap: -40;
    column-gap: -40;
  background: transparent;
                         }

   .menu .menu-item {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
            }
```

but when I convert it to react it did not work. it's look like this:[menu page in react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrXbq.png) it look fine only if the number is equal on both sides (such as two products for each side).
recat code for menu page:

```
 <div  className={styles["tabcontent"] + " " + styles["menu"]}>
        {console.log(posts)}
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <Link key={post.id} href={`/product/${encodeURIComponent(post.slug)}`}>
             <MenuItem key={post.id} post={post} />
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
```

MenuItem component code:

```
function MenuItem({ post }) {
return (
  <>
   <div className={styles.menuItem}>
  <div className={styles.menuImg}>

  <Image src={post.product_image} height={70} width={60} />
  </div>

  <div className={styles.menuText}>
  <p><span>{post.title}</span><strong>SR {post.regular_price}</strong></p>
  
  </div>

  <button >
    Add to Cart
  </button>
  </div>
</>
  );
    }
```

can you help me please or if there is another way to do it ?

Comment: pleeease can anyone help me :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.